# Exception with boost::locale on windows

Tags: c++, boost

I try to use boost::locale to tokenize string.
I run it on windows 8 64 bit. I use VS 2015 to build my project.
Boost version 1.63
I use code from the sample file - boundary.cpp:

```
generator gen;
locale loc = gen("");
locale::global(loc);
wcout.imbue(loc);
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::string text("Hello World!Linux2.6 and Windows7 is word and number!");
boundary::ssegment_index index(boundary::word, text.begin(), text.end());
```

Last line throws the exception:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   std::use_facet >(...) returned nullptr.

Comment: Surely you could have provided a compileable example?

Comment: Please see below:

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::locale;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
 generator gen;
 locale loc = gen("");
 locale::global(loc);
 wcout.imbue(loc);

 std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

 std::string text("Hello World!Linux2.6 and Windows7 is word and number!");

 boundary::ssegment_index index(boundary::word, text.begin(), text.end());

    return 0;
}

Comment: I compiled it in VC2015.  boundary::ssegment_index index(boundary::word, text.begin(), text.end());  - throws the exception: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD81BF8B9C in BoostLocale.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_cast at memory location 0x000000DD42C1EB58.

Comment: I found the issue - it seems that the problem was that I link with boost statically. After I switch to dynamic link with boost it's works.